# failed to parse stage name "huggingface-pytorch-training:xxxx:latest": invalid reference format

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

There is a problem while building a particular docker image

The image name is: `763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/huggingface-pytorch-training:1.10.2-transformers4.17.0-gpu-py38-cu113-ubuntu20.04:latest`. This image name is from the official list of images by AWS:
https://github.com/aws/deep-learning-containers/blob/master/available_images.md

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
ARG AWS_ACCOUNT_ID
ARG AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
FROM 763104351884.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com/huggingface-pytorch-training:1.10.2-transformers4.17.0-gpu-py38-cu113-ubuntu20.04:latest
```

The following command was run:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region ${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION} | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 763104351884.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com

docker compose build --build-arg AWS_ACCOUNT_ID=763104351884 --build-arg
```

The error is the following:

```
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1 --no-cache
[+] Building 0.2s (2/2) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                         
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 519B                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
failed to solve: failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to parse stage name "763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/huggingface-pytorch-training:1.10.2-transformers4.17.0-gpu-py38-cu113-ubuntu20.04:latest": invalid reference format
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove the trailing `:latest` from the image name. Docker image names can't have two colons (:) in the string, which was causing the issue.

So once I changed `763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/huggingface-pytorch-training:1.10.2-transformers4.17.0-gpu-py38-cu113-ubuntu20.04:latest` -> `763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/huggingface-pytorch-training:1.10.2-transformers4.17.0-gpu-py38-cu113-ubuntu20.04` the container started building.